# How do I label my rows and columns in order to work better with them?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset with the emisisons of Canada:

[image]

and I would like to label the first row to "years" and the second to "emissions".
For example, if I dont do this how can I name my variables in "aes" in ggplot () function:

`ggplot(CAN_emissions, aes(___, ___))`

Comment: rownames(Canada)[1] = 'years'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add a name to the first row, we can use `rownames(CAN_emissions) <- "emissions"` though this won't help much as the years data points are in the column titles, not in a row of their own.

Generally speaking, you'll struggle to plot the data while it is in a 'wide' format like this. A better solution is to convert all of the year columns into rows. The problem of row names will then disappear. We can do this like so:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)

CAN_emissions <- CAN_emissions %>% 
  pivot_longer(-country, names_to = "year", values_to = "emissions")
```

The data can then be plotted directly:

```
ggplot(CAN_emissions, aes(x = year, y = emissions)) + geom_point()
```

**Data:**

```
CAN_emissions <- tibble(
  country = c("Canada"),
  `1800` = 0.00568,
  `1801` = 0.00561,
  `1802` = 0.00555
)
```

Comment: Thank u so much, any advice when importing this kind of data so that i don´t struggle with this label formats?
Also, i did not know the pivot_longer() function... is this a thing that people are used to do?
P.S. I am new to coding, sorry for these questions ;)

Comment: It's hard to give advice about reading in data as it changes so much between sources, though the 'Import Dataset' button in RStudio might help as it gives a preview of what the table will look like. The best way to learn coding is to solve problems, so you're already on the right track.